# "Bad interpreter: No such file" error with PIP, python 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7, pip, mako

I am trying to run the following code:

```
pip install mako
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have tried moving pip into the same directory as Python-2.7.11 (usr/lib/Python-2.7.11) and moving Python into the same directory as pip.  I have seen a couple of diffrent similar instances to this issue however none seemed to answer my question. This is on linux, and I installed Python-2.7.11 to replace the native 2.6 build that was on the machine.  Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that pip was look for a python executable that wasn't there.  I had to link it with:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/Python-2.7.11/python python2.7
```

Hopefully this helps someone with the same issue.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Was seeing this same issue, I was working in a directory which had an `'` in its directory path/name.
However, moving to a directory without apostrophe (`'`) solved this issue.

```
bash: /home/user/share/f x/User's Files/x/x_y/T/docs/venv/bin/pip: "/home/user/share/f: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```